# Upload Progress Bar in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, progress-bar, contact-form-7

I reproduced successfully the solution described
[here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-progress-bar-in-file-upload-on-submit-form/)
to add one progress bar to CF7.
But my Contact Form 7 doesn't validate required fields and does't show any response message after one click on the submit button.

I tried to adapt the code in scripts.js (contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js) from Version 3.5.3 to the newer version 5.1

Here is the changed scripts.js:

```
( function( $ ) {

    'use strict';
        // start
        var progressbox  = jQuery('#progressbox');
        var progressbar     = jQuery('#progressbar');
        var statustxt   = jQuery('#statustxt');
        var submitbutton    = jQuery("#SubmitButton");
        var myform  = jQuery("#wpcf7-form");
        var output2  = jQuery("#output2");
        var completed   = '0%';
        //end

    if ( typeof wpcf7 === 'undefined' || wpcf7 === null ) {
        return;
    }

    wpcf7 = $.extend( {
        cached: 0,
        inputs: []
    }, wpcf7 );

    $( function() {
        wpcf7.supportHtml5 = ( function() {
            var features = {};
            var input = document.createElement( 'input' );

            features.placeholder = 'placeholder' in input;

            var inputTypes = [ 'email', 'url', 'tel', 'number', 'range', 'date' ];

            $.each( inputTypes, function( index, value ) {
                input.setAttribute( 'type', value );
                features[ value ] = input.type !== 'text';
            } );

            return features;
        } )();

        $( 'div.wpcf7 > form' ).each( function() {
            var $form = $( this );
            wpcf7.initForm( $form );

            if ( wpcf7.cached ) {
                wpcf7.refill( $form );
            }
        } );
    } );

    wpcf7.getId = function( form ) {
        return parseInt( $( 'input[name="_wpcf7"]', form ).val(), 10 );
    };

    wpcf7.initForm = function( form ) {
        var $form = $( form );

        $form.submit( function( event ) {
            if ( ! wpcf7.supportHtml5.placeholder ) {
                $( '[placeholder].placeheld', $form ).each( function( i, n ) {
                    $( n ).val( '' ).removeClass( 'placeheld' );
                } );
            }

            if ( typeof window.FormData === 'function' ) {
                wpcf7.submit( $form );
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        } );

        $( '.wpcf7-submit', $form ).after( '<span class="ajax-loader"></span>' );

        wpcf7.toggleSubmit( $form );

        $form.on( 'click', '.wpcf7-acceptance', function() {
            wpcf7.toggleSubmit( $form );
        } );

        // Exclusive Checkbox
        $( '.wpcf7-exclusive-checkbox', $form ).on( 'click', 'input:checkbox', function() {
            var name = $( this ).attr( 'name' );
            $form.find( 'input:checkbox[name="' + name + '"]' ).not( this ).prop( 'checked', false );
        } );

        // Free Text Option for Checkboxes and Radio Buttons
        $( '.wpcf7-list-item.has-free-text', $form ).each( function() {
            var $freetext = $( ':input.wpcf7-free-text', this );
            var $wrap = $( this ).closest( '.wpcf7-form-control' );

            if ( $( ':checkbox, :radio', this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                $freetext.prop( 'disabled', false );
            } else {
                $freetext.prop( 'disabled', true );
            }

            $wrap.on( 'change', ':checkbox, :radio', function() {
                var $cb = $( '.has-free-text', $wrap ).find( ':checkbox, :radio' );

                if ( $cb.is( ':checked' ) ) {
                    $freetext.prop( 'disabled', false ).focus();
                } else {
                    $freetext.prop( 'disabled', true );
                }
            } );
        } );

        // Placeholder Fallback
        if ( ! wpcf7.supportHtml5.placeholder ) {
            $( '[placeholder]', $form ).each( function() {
                $( this ).val( $( this ).attr( 'placeholder' ) );
                $( this ).addClass( 'placeheld' );

                $( this ).focus( function() {
                    if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'placeheld' ) ) {
                        $( this ).val( '' ).removeClass( 'placeheld' );
                    }
                } );

                $( this ).blur( function() {
                    if ( '' === $( this ).val() ) {
                        $( this ).val( $( this ).attr( 'placeholder' ) );
                        $( this ).addClass( 'placeheld' );
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }

        if ( wpcf7.jqueryUi && ! wpcf7.supportHtml5.date ) {
            $form.find( 'input.wpcf7-date[type="date"]' ).each( function() {
                $( this ).datepicker( {
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    minDate: new Date( $( this ).attr( 'min' ) ),
                    maxDate: new Date( $( this ).attr( 'max' ) )
                } );
            } );
        }

        if ( wpcf7.jqueryUi && ! wpcf7.supportHtml5.number ) {
            $form.find( 'input.wpcf7-number[type="number"]' ).each( function() {
                $( this ).spinner( {
                    min: $( this ).attr( 'min' ),
                    max: $( this ).attr( 'max' ),
                    step: $( this ).attr( 'step' )
                } );
            } );
        }

        // Character Count
        $( '.wpcf7-character-count', $form ).each( function() {
            var $count = $( this );
            var name = $count.attr( 'data-target-name' );
            var down = $count.hasClass( 'down' );
            var starting = parseInt( $count.attr( 'data-starting-value' ), 10 );
            var maximum = parseInt( $count.attr( 'data-maximum-value' ), 10 );
            var minimum = parseInt( $count.attr( 'data-minimum-value' ), 10 );

            var updateCount = function( target ) {
                var $target = $( target );
                var length = $target.val().length;
                var count = down ? starting - length : length;
                $count.attr( 'data-current-value', count );
                $count.text( count );

                if ( maximum && maximum < length ) {
                    $count.addClass( 'too-long' );
                } else {
                    $count.removeClass( 'too-long' );
                }

                if ( minimum && length < minimum ) {
                    $count.addClass( 'too-short' );
                } else {
                    $count.removeClass( 'too-short' );
                }
            };

            $( ':input[name="' + name + '"]', $form ).each( function() {
                updateCount( this );

                $( this ).keyup( function() {
                    updateCount( this );
                } );
            } );
        } );

        // URL Input Correction
        $form.on( 'change', '.wpcf7-validates-as-url', function() {
            var val = $.trim( $( this ).val() );

            if ( val
            && ! val.match( /^[a-z][a-z0-9.+-]*:/i )
            && -1 !== val.indexOf( '.' ) ) {
                val = val.replace( /^\/+/, '' );
                val = 'http://' + val;
            }

            $( this ).val( val );
        } );
    };

    wpcf7.submit = function( form ) {
        if ( typeof window.FormData !== 'function' ) {
            return;
        }

        var $form = $( form );

        $( '.ajax-loader', $form ).addClass( 'is-active' );

        wpcf7.clearResponse( $form );

        var formData = new FormData( $form.get( 0 ) );

        var detail = {
            id: $form.closest( 'div.wpcf7' ).attr( 'id' ),
            status: 'init',
            inputs: [],
            formData: formData
        };

        $.each( $form.serializeArray(), function( i, field ) {
            if ( '_wpcf7' == field.name ) {
                detail.contactFormId = field.value;
            } else if ( '_wpcf7_version' == field.name ) {
                detail.pluginVersion = field.value;
            } else if ( '_wpcf7_locale' == field.name ) {
                detail.contactFormLocale = field.value;
            } else if ( '_wpcf7_unit_tag' == field.name ) {
                detail.unitTag = field.value;
            } else if ( '_wpcf7_container_post' == field.name ) {
                detail.containerPostId = field.value;
            } else if ( field.name.match( /^_wpcf7_\w+_free_text_/ ) ) {
                var owner = field.name.replace( /^_wpcf7_\w+_free_text_/, '' );
                detail.inputs.push( {
                    name: owner + '-free-text',
                    value: field.value
                } );
            } else if ( field.name.match( /^_/ ) ) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                detail.inputs.push( field );
            }
        } );

        wpcf7.triggerEvent( $form.closest( 'div.wpcf7' ), 'beforesubmit', detail );

        var ajaxSuccess = function( data, status, xhr, $form ) {
            detail.id = $( data.into ).attr( 'id' );
            detail.status = data.status;
            detail.apiResponse = data;

            var $message = $( '.wpcf7-response-output', $form );
            // start
            submitbutton.attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
            statustxt.empty();
            progressbox.slideDown(); //show progressbar
            progressbar.width(completed); //initial value 0% of progressbar
            statustxt.html(completed); //set status text
            statustxt.css('color','#000'); //initial color of status text
            //end

            // start
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) { //on progress
                progressbar.width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
                statustxt.html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text
                if(percentComplete>50) {
                    statustxt.css('color','#fff'); //change status text to white after 50%
                }
            },
            //end

            switch ( data.status ) {
                case 'validation_failed':
                    $.each( data.invalidFields, function( i, n ) {
                        $( n.into, $form ).each( function() {
                            wpcf7.notValidTip( this, n.message );
                            $( '.wpcf7-form-control', this ).addClass( 'wpcf7-not-valid' );
                            $( '[aria-invalid]', this ).attr( 'aria-invalid', 'true' );
                        } );
                    } );

                    $message.addClass( 'wpcf7-validation-errors' );
                    $form.addClass( 'invalid' );

                    wpcf7.triggerEvent( data.into, 'invalid', detail );
                    break;
                case 'acceptance_missing':
                    $message.addClass( 'wpcf7-acceptance-missing' );
                    $form.addClass( 'unaccepted' );

                    wpcf7.triggerEvent( data.into, 'unaccepted', detail );
                    break;
                case 'spam':
                    $message.addClass( 'wpcf7-spam-blocked' );
                    $form.addClass( 'spam' );

                    wpcf7.triggerEvent( data.into, 'spam', detail );
                    break;
                case 'aborted':
                    $message.addClass( 'wpcf7-aborted' );
                    $form.addClass( 'aborted' );

                    wpcf7.triggerEvent( data.into, 'aborted', detail );
                    break;
                case 'mail_sent':
                    $message.addClass( 'wpcf7-mail-sent-ok' );
                    $form.addClass( 'sent' );

                    wpcf7.triggerEvent( data.into, 'mailsent', detail );
                    break;
                case 'mail_failed':
                    $message.addClass( 'wpcf7-mail-sent-ng' );
                    $form.addClass( 'failed' );

                    wpcf7.triggerEvent( data.into, 'mailfailed', detail );
                    break;
                default:
                    var customStatusClass = 'custom-'
                        + data.status.replace( /[^0-9a-z]+/i, '-' );
                    $message.addClass( 'wpcf7-' + customStatusClass );
                    $form.addClass( customStatusClass );
            }

            wpcf7.refill( $form, data );

            wpcf7.triggerEvent( data.into, 'submit', detail );

            if ( 'mail_sent' == data.status ) {
                $form.each( function() {
                    this.reset();
                } );

                wpcf7.toggleSubmit( $form );
            }

            if ( ! wpcf7.supportHtml5.placeholder ) {
                $form.find( '[placeholder].placeheld' ).each( function( i, n ) {
                    $( n ).val( $( n ).attr( 'placeholder' ) );
                } );
            }

            $message.html( '' ).append( data.message ).slideDown( 'fast' );
            $message.attr( 'role', 'alert' );

            $( '.screen-reader-response', $form.closest( '.wpcf7' ) ).each( function() {
                var $response = $( this );
                $response.html( '' ).attr( 'role', '' ).append( data.message );

                if ( data.invalidFields ) {
                    var $invalids = $( '<ul></ul>' );

                    $.each( data.invalidFields, function( i, n ) {
                        if ( n.idref ) {
                            var $li = $( '<li></li>' ).append( $( '<a></a>' ).attr( 'href', '#' + n.idref ).append( n.message ) );
                        } else {
                            var $li = $( '<li></li>' ).append( n.message );
                        }

                        $invalids.append( $li );
                    } );

                    $response.append( $invalids );
                }

                $response.attr( 'role', 'alert' ).focus();
            } );
        };

        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: wpcf7.apiSettings.getRoute(
                '/contact-forms/' + wpcf7.getId( $form ) + '/feedback' ),
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        } ).done( function( data, status, xhr ) {
            ajaxSuccess( data, status, xhr, $form );
            $( '.ajax-loader', $form ).removeClass( 'is-active' );
        } ).fail( function( xhr, status, error ) {
            var $e = $( '<div class="ajax-error"></div>' ).text( error.message );
            $form.after( $e );
        } );
    };

    wpcf7.triggerEvent = function( target, name, detail ) {
        var $target = $( target );

        /* DOM event */
        var event = new CustomEvent( 'wpcf7' + name, {
            bubbles: true,
            detail: detail
        } );

        $target.get( 0 ).dispatchEvent( event );

        /* jQuery event */
        $target.trigger( 'wpcf7:' + name, detail );
        $target.trigger( name + '.wpcf7', detail ); // deprecated
    };

    wpcf7.toggleSubmit = function( form, state ) {
        var $form = $( form );
        var $submit = $( 'input:submit', $form );

        if ( typeof state !== 'undefined' ) {
            $submit.prop( 'disabled', ! state );
            return;
        }

        if ( $form.hasClass( 'wpcf7-acceptance-as-validation' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $submit.prop( 'disabled', false );

        $( '.wpcf7-acceptance', $form ).each( function() {
            var $span = $( this );
            var $input = $( 'input:checkbox', $span );

            if ( ! $span.hasClass( 'optional' ) ) {
                if ( $span.hasClass( 'invert' ) && $input.is( ':checked' )
                || ! $span.hasClass( 'invert' ) && ! $input.is( ':checked' ) ) {
                    $submit.prop( 'disabled', true );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } );
    };

    wpcf7.notValidTip = function( target, message ) {
        var $target = $( target );
        $( '.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $target ).remove();
        $( '<span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip"></span>' )
            .text( message ).appendTo( $target );

        if ( $target.is( '.use-floating-validation-tip *' ) ) {
            var fadeOut = function( target ) {
                $( target ).not( ':hidden' ).animate( {
                    opacity: 0
                }, 'fast', function() {
                    $( this ).css( { 'z-index': -100 } );
                } );
            };

            $target.on( 'mouseover', '.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', function() {
                fadeOut( this );
            } );

            $target.on( 'focus', ':input', function() {
                fadeOut( $( '.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $target ) );
            } );
        }
    };

    wpcf7.refill = function( form, data ) {
        var $form = $( form );

        var refillCaptcha = function( $form, items ) {
            $.each( items, function( i, n ) {
                $form.find( ':input[name="' + i + '"]' ).val( '' );
                $form.find( 'img.wpcf7-captcha-' + i ).attr( 'src', n );
                var match = /([0-9]+)\.(png|gif|jpeg)$/.exec( n );
                $form.find( 'input:hidden[name="_wpcf7_captcha_challenge_' + i + '"]' ).attr( 'value', match[ 1 ] );
            } );
        };

        var refillQuiz = function( $form, items ) {
            $.each( items, function( i, n ) {
                $form.find( ':input[name="' + i + '"]' ).val( '' );
                $form.find( ':input[name="' + i + '"]' ).siblings( 'span.wpcf7-quiz-label' ).text( n[ 0 ] );
                $form.find( 'input:hidden[name="_wpcf7_quiz_answer_' + i + '"]' ).attr( 'value', n[ 1 ] );
            } );
        };

        if ( typeof data === 'undefined' ) {
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'GET',
                url: wpcf7.apiSettings.getRoute(
                    '/contact-forms/' + wpcf7.getId( $form ) + '/refill' ),
                beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                    var nonce = $form.find( ':input[name="_wpnonce"]' ).val();

                    if ( nonce ) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', nonce );
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            } ).done( function( data, status, xhr ) {
                if ( data.captcha ) {
                    refillCaptcha( $form, data.captcha );
                }

                if ( data.quiz ) {
                    refillQuiz( $form, data.quiz );
                }
            } );

        } else {
            if ( data.captcha ) {
                refillCaptcha( $form, data.captcha );
            }

            if ( data.quiz ) {
                refillQuiz( $form, data.quiz );
            }
        }
    };

    wpcf7.clearResponse = function( form ) {
        var $form = $( form );
        $form.removeClass( 'invalid spam sent failed' );
        $form.siblings( '.screen-reader-response' ).html( '' ).attr( 'role', '' );

        $( '.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $form ).remove();
        $( '[aria-invalid]', $form ).attr( 'aria-invalid', 'false' );
        $( '.wpcf7-form-control', $form ).removeClass( 'wpcf7-not-valid' );

        $( '.wpcf7-response-output', $form )
            .hide().empty().removeAttr( 'role' )
            .removeClass( 'wpcf7-mail-sent-ok wpcf7-mail-sent-ng wpcf7-validation-errors wpcf7-spam-blocked' );
    };

    wpcf7.apiSettings.getRoute = function( path ) {
        var url = wpcf7.apiSettings.root;

        url = url.replace(
            wpcf7.apiSettings.namespace,
            wpcf7.apiSettings.namespace + path );

        return url;
    };

} )( jQuery );

/*
 * Polyfill for Internet Explorer
 * See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent
 */
( function () {
    if ( typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ) return false;

    function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
        params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
        var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
        evt.initCustomEvent( event,
            params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
        return evt;
    }

    CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

    window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
} )();
```

The progessbar works very good, mails are sended, but if the upload reach 100% the ajax-loader is still spinnig and the success message does not appear.

Can someone help to get it working?

Comment: This is a wall of code. Nobody is going to debug all that. What do you see in the browser's developer tools? Any error messages? Have you looked at the XHR in the Network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a wall of code. Sorry about this. 
I aded successfully the progressbox with workig progress process. See the code below.
The issue now is, that the upload process is triggered before required field are validated. 
What can I do to validate the required field, before the upload starts?
Any suggestions?

```
$.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: wpcf7.apiSettings.getRoute(
                '/contact-forms/' + wpcf7.getId( $form ) + '/feedback' ),
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,


            // add progress box        
            beforeSend: function() { 
            progressbox.slideDown(); //show progressbar
            progressbar.width(completed); //initial value 0% of progressbar
            statustxt.html(completed); //set status text
            statustxt.css('color','#000'); //initial color of status text
            //e.preventDefault();
            },
            //end 

            // show upload process   
            xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total);
                //upload progress
                progressbar.width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
                statustxt.html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text  
                if(percentComplete>50) {
                    statustxt.css('color','#fff'); //change status text to white after 50% 
                }
            }
       }, false);



       return xhr;
    },
            //end           

        } ).done( function( data, status, xhr ) {
            ajaxSuccess( data, status, xhr, $form );
            $( '.ajax-loader', $form ).removeClass( 'is-active' );

            // hide progressbox
            myform.resetForm();  // reset form
            submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
            progressbox.slideUp(); // hide progressbar
            //end 
        } ).fail( function( xhr, status, error ) {
            var $e = $( '<div class="ajax-error"></div>' ).text( error.message );
            $form.after( $e );
        } );
    };
```